# Can we have a way to edit in mobile chat?

Tags: feature-request, edits, chat, mobile-web

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Missing features of mobile chat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126874/missing-features-of-mobile-chat)

Mobile chat is very slick. But since typing on mobile is not, a way to edit chat messages via mobile would be very helpful. Can we have such a feature?

Comment: Even MOAR features listed in [Missing features of mobile chat](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126874/missing-features-of-mobile-chat)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is an edit feature, if you'd like to edit your last message. From the mobile chat window, click "Menu" and then "edit last". This will populate the text field with your last message, allowing you to edit it. The same menu also offers:

- all rooms (see the list of chat rooms)
- this room (see the starred messages, transcript, leave the room, search)
- non-mobile view (switch to the full-screen version)
- people (see who is in the room)
- my rooms (see the list of rooms you're also in)
- delete last (delete the last message you wrote)

Comment: Oh, awesome! Didn't see that