# Missing features of mobile chat

Tags: feature-request, chat, mobile-web

Mobile chat is missing a lot of features (understandable, as it's mobile). However, there are a number of features not currently implemented that are almost necessities:

- **Replies** — Sure, we can type "@so-and-so" and hope we've gotten the so-and-so correct, but this doesn't work well when replying to a specific message back up the queue. Plus, there's no Tab button on many devices, so we can't even type the first few letters of their name and hit Tab to complete it! (Tab completion doesn't even work when you have a full bluetooth keyboard connected to an iPad.)
- **Stars** — There's no way to star messages in mobile chat. (Unless the message has already been starred by someone else, then you can click on their star to add your own.)
- **Edits** — There's Menu > Edit last, but that only works for the last message. There's no way to edit messages more than two back.

Can any of these be added?

Comment: Permalinks while we're at it. Oh, and none of this works on a tablet.

Comment: @Manishearth Actually, that's the only mobile device I have! All my mobile chatting has been done on an iPad.

Comment: I use a mix of the mobile site on a phone and the regular site on a tablet. And I use the main site whenever I want to write long answers with math formatting (annoying on the iPad, you have tap three times just to type `\`) But the profusion of mouseover features makes it a bit hard to use the iPad at times. Especially chat.

Comment: **DO WANT THESE** please balpha!

Comment: I really miss the ability to "reply" on the mobile app!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All of this is now implemented by default in the [February 2016](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/273727/test-the-new-mobile-chat) update to the chat web app mobile theme. Huzzah!

- tap the message in chat needing action and then use the toolbar near the top of the window

[image]

Comment: Hallelujah!!!!!

Answer (score 2):

This was bugging me so I [made an app](https://stackapps.com/questions/4659/chatsey-an-android-app-for-se-chat).

It makes replying, starring, flagging and editing all much easier, and provides auto-completion of names.

Android only, unless someone's willing to try and put it through Apple Review...

Comment: The app is for stackexchange chat only not for stackoverflow. Sniff! Sniff! T_T

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto ORLY? It should work on both. This was an earlier problem with the app, but it should be fixed now.

Comment: I have downloaded the latest one. Just 2 hours ago.