# Mobile site chat transcript link not working

Tags: bug, chat

> Slightly related: [Missing features of mobile chat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126874/missing-features-of-mobile-chat)

On the mobile site, if I have opened a link to a chat message(eg [this](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/71?m=3778089#3778089), [force-mobile-link of the same](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/71?mobile=true&m=3778089#3778089)), I get that day's transcript, without the yellow highlighting. I suppose that's a bug as well, bit I'm not too concerned with it.

The issue is, when I click "normal view", instead of redirecting me to the desktop version of the same page, it redirects me to the [desktop version of today's transcript](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/71?mobile=false). Basically, all it does is make `mobile=false` the query string with complete disregard for the existing query/`#`-anchor.

The functionality of the link ought to be to give [this](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/71?mobile=false&m=3778089#3778089)(same example as above). It's extremely annoying to have to insert `mobile=false&` into the URL on a mobile device--and it's probably nonintuitive for a non-programmer either.

Comment: I don't know what or where this "half-baked mobile site" you're talking about is. I use the mobile site all the time on my iPwn, and it's *awesome*. Then again, I don't use chat at all, so maybe that's the issue. If so, you might want to limit your rants to the "half-baked chat support on the mobile site".

Comment: @TheEstablishment well, maybe a bit strongly stated.. It's not half-baked-i use it on my phone and iPad regularly--more than the desktop. I sort of wanted to garner some publicity for the other question ;) I'll fix it,1sec

Comment: The yellow highlighting for the mobile transcript is fixed now.

Comment: @balpha ironically, I would say that's the harder of the two fixes.  Then again, I dunno...

Comment: No, it was trivial. The yellow background color was just missing from the mobile CSS file.

Comment: @balpha oh, makes sense.. Quick question: why does the mobile site have/need mouseovers for badges and tags?

Comment: Not sure what you're talking about. There are no badges in chat (mobile or not), and what does "have/need mouseovers" mean?

Comment: @balpha Im saying that tags/badge have mouseovers on the mobile _site_. Don't see whywe _need_ that. Irrelevant really, and insignificant.--just that since all unnecessary stuff is culled from the mobile site, I was wondering why this is still there :/