# Suggestions when replying on Mobile site

Tags: feature-request, mobile-web, comment-replies

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Missing features of mobile chat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126874/missing-features-of-mobile-chat)

On mobile site, when I type `@` in comment, no suggestion is displayed for tap-to-complete. When comment-stream size is large, I always have to scroll up and down many times to fill a complicated name. Its error prone too.

As tag suggestions work fine on mobile site, I don't think there may be technical difficulty for it.

Please, add this feature.

Comment: In well over 90% of cases, [all you need are the first 3 characters of their name](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work), which really isn't that hard to type. Or remember.

Comment: Yes, but it may be conflicting because first 3 characters may be shared with many ones. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125994/how-to-reply-to-one-user-among-two-having-same-names

Comment: @SachinShekhar - Conflicts like that are rare in my experience, but tap-to-complete sounds like a fine idea.

Comment: Voting to reopen - this is about the mobile site theme, **not chat**